# $\int f d\mu = \lim_{r \downarrow 1} \sum_{k = -\infty}^{k =\infty} r^k \mu(x \in X : r^k \leq f(x) < r^{k+1}) $

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

$\int f d\mu = \displaystyle \lim_{r \downarrow 1} \sum_{k = -\infty}^{k =\infty} r^k \mu(x \in X : r^k \leq f(x) < r^{k+1}) $ where $\lim_{r \downarrow 1} $ r is approaching to 1 from above.

My ideas:

I define the set $E_n^r = \{x \in X: r^n \leq f(x) < r^{n+1}\}$ for $n \geq 1, r>1$.

I also define $\displaystyle G_N^r = \sum_{n=-N}^N r^n \mu (E_n^ R)$ and $\displaystyle g_N^r = \sum_{n=-N}^N r^n \chi _{E_n^ R}$

We know that $G_N^ r = \int g_N^r d\mu$ and $g_N \leq g_{N+1}$ for all $N \geq 1, r>1$. Then I need to show that:

- $\lim_{N \to \infty} g_N^r$ exist and is equal to $g^r$.
- Using monotone convergence therorem, $\lim_{N \to \infty} G_N^r=\int g^r $
  and finally see that:

$$\lim_{r \downarrow 1} \int \phi^r d \mu = \int f d \mu$$

Am I in the right path? Can someone help me to complete the details of the proof?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We clearly need to assume $f$ is a nonnegative measurable function. I will further assume that $f$ is integrable; I don't know if this hypothesis is necessary. I would say that you were trying to be too fancy. Exchanging limits and integrals wasn't necessarily going to work here, noting that the summands of $g_r$ tend (in many cases) to the zero function pointwise a.e. If you can, go for elementary bounds before employing the big guns.

---

Since the $E_{n,r}:=\{x\in X:r^n\le f(x)<r^{n+1}\}$ form a disjoint partition of $X$, it's immediate that the function $g_r=\sum_{n\in\Bbb Z}r^n\cdot\chi_{E_{n,r}}$ is a well-defined and finite measurable function $X\to\Bbb R$.

You would like to show that $\lim_{r\to1^+}\int_Xg_r=\int_X f$. Define $g'_r=\sum_{n\in\Bbb Z}r^{n+1}\cdot\chi_{E_{n,r}}$. For $r>1$, the inequalities $g_r\le f\le g'_r$ are clear. Because integration preserves inequalities, it suffices to show that $\lim_{r\to1^+}\int_X(g'_r-g_r)=0$.

However, note that $g'_r-g_r=(r-1)\cdot g_r$; moreover, since $g_r\le f$ it follows each $g_r$ is integrable with integral bounded by $\|f\|$. Hence the integrals $\int_X(g'_r-g_r)$ are bounded by $(r-1)\cdot\|f\|$ which obviously vanishes as $r\to1^+$. Done!

Answer (score 1):

We will use the following version of convergence theorem:

> **Theorem.** Let $f$ and $f_1, f_2, \ldots$ be non-negative measurable functions on a measure space $(X, \Sigma, \mu)$ such that $f_n \leq f$ and $f_n \to f$ everywhere on $X$. Then
> $$ \lim_{n\to\infty} \int_X f_n \, \mathrm{d}\mu = \int_X f \, \mathrm{d}\mu. $$

It is an easy consequence of Fatou's lemma, and the proof can be found [here](https://sos440.blogspot.com/2022/01/dominated-convergence-theorem-revisited.html). Now returning to OP's problem, let us write $s = \log r$ for simplicity. Then monotone convergence theorem (or Tonelli's theorem) tells that

\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} r^k \mu(E_k^r)
&= \sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} \int_X \exp\left( ks \right) \mathbf{1}_{E_k^r} \, \mathrm{d}\mu \\
&= \sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} \int_X \exp\left( \left\lfloor \frac{\log f}{s} \right\rfloor s \right) \mathbf{1}_{E_k^r} \, \mathrm{d}\mu \\
&= \int_X \exp\left( \left\lfloor \frac{\log f}{s} \right\rfloor s \right) \left[ \sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} \mathbf{1}_{E_k^r} \right] \, \mathrm{d}\mu \\
&= \int_X \exp\left( \left\lfloor \frac{\log f}{s} \right\rfloor s \right) \mathbf{1}_{\{f > 0\}} \, \mathrm{d}\mu.
\end{align*}

Define $f_s = \exp\left( \left\lfloor \frac{\log f}{s} \right\rfloor s \right) \mathbf{1}_{\{f > 0\}}$. Then it is clear that

1. $0 \leq f_s \leq f$, and
2. $f_s \to f$ as $s \to 0^+$.

By invoking the above convergence theorem, we find that

$$ \sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} r_m^k \mu(E_k^{r_m}) = \int_X f_{\log r_m} \, \mathrm{d}\mu \to \int_X f \, \mathrm{d}\mu $$

for any choice of sequence $r_m \downarrow 1$, hence the claim follows.